# how to position an element on top of another element?

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I have a menu and a search box. I would like to put the search box along with menu items. But my menu is being built in a different file in a div called 'custommenu' which uses the following css:

```
#custommenu {
  position:relative;
  z-index:999;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  width: 918px;
  background-color: #FB0A51; 
  border-top-left-radius: 10px 10px; 
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 10px 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px 10px; 
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 10px 10px;
}
```

Whereas I have my search box in a separate file which looks like this:

```
 <div class="header">
   some code
   <div class="quick-access">
      some code
   <php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>;
   </div>
 </div>
```

I tried adding the following to the css file so that the search box comes on top of the menu but it did not work

```
 .header .form-search { 
   position:absolute; 
   right:29px;  
   z-index:1000; 
   top: 80px;  
   width:315px;  
   height:30px;  
   padding:1px 0 0 16px; 
 }
```

Still the search box gets hidden behind the menu. I would like to have the search box n the menu. How do i do it?

EDIT: Here's the css of the div's which contains the search box,

```
 .header { width:930px; margin:0 auto; padding:10px; text-align:right; position:relative; z-index:10; border-top:3px solid #3C3C42;}
 .header .quick-access { float:right; width:600px;margin-top:-125px; padding:28px 10px 0 0; }
 .header .form-search { position:relative; top: 100px;left: 300px; z-index:9999; width:315px; height:30px; padding:1px 0 0 16px; }
```

And this is how it looks right now, (purple links - quick access, white box is search which is going behind the pink 'custommenu' area. I would like to have the white box on the pink area. And all of this is inside 'header')

[image: z-index issue o/p]

Comment: Is it an oversight or intentional that your PHP does not have a closing tag?

Comment: Make sure the parent element has a position of relative. Also make sure the parent element has a z-index. This will help fix a bug in IE.

Comment: Or an invalid opening tag: `<php` -> `<?php`

Comment: @Josh: I have edited the question and now it has the php closing tag.

Comment: @BenCarey: Well d search box is in two divs, 'header' and 'quick access'. The header tag has position relative but 'quick-access' is just floated to right and I have positioned search box absolutely. Is that wrong?

Comment: @ivn Quick Access must have a position of relative and then the menu will position relatively to the quick-access div.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@all

Sorry for replying very late. But I found the solution after a little bit of fiddling. I set the z-index of my header to a higher value than my custommenu. Since my header contains the search box it needed to have a higher value for the search box to come over the menu.

The code looks like this now

```
.header{ position: relative; z-index: 4000; }
 .header search { position: relative; z-index: 99999; }
.custommenu { position: relative; z-index: 1000 ;}
```

This perfectly got my search box on top of my menu aligned. Thanks again for all those who helped. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `float`? or `display:block;`
If I was using this code, I would write the css like this:

```
position:relative;
left:some value;
top:some value;
Z-index: -999
```

Comment: use float:left to parent element. and if u want down this. do clear both. if u do0nt like float: go with:display:inline-block;<br> and *display:inline;<br> and Zoom:1;

Comment: float doesn't work because it moves the 'quick-access' div too. I want to only move the search box which is represented by '.header .form-search'

Answer (score 0):

The search box appearing behind the menu sounds like a z-index issue - perhaps the container of the menu has a higher z-index to the search box, try changing the searchbox z-index to 999999.

Comment: That dint work. I have attached the screenshot and elaborated my problem more, if that gives you any ideas.

Comment: Hi is there a public url where we can look at this. - I can see It is the pink box that is on top of the search box. These are usually pretty easy to fix once it is looked at with something like firebug or developer tools etc

Comment: I am afraid its on my localhost and hence I cannot provide you any public url to have a look at this. However, if you could tell me which elements u suspect might be causing the problem, I can look up in firebug and can write it back about them here.

Answer (score 0):

`z-index` requires non-static positioning however it is not clear from your code examples which type of positioning is actually used by the elements you are trying to stack with `z-index`.

Either way here is a very helpful tool which might help you determine which type of positioning you have to use for your elements in regards to how they relate.

http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp